# PubSub GKE Connectivity Issue - Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud Stream and trying to deploy it onto GKE and connect it to PubSub to send messages. Application works perfectly fine locally, sending messages to a specific topic on GCP but once deployed on GKE, I get following error:

```
ERROR 1 --- [ main] o.s.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService : Failed to create producer binding; retrying in 30 seconds
```

`org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.BinderException: Exception thrown while building outbound endpoint at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:241) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:91) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:320) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:285) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:294) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:298) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:142) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at com.pubsub.sender.SenderApplication.main(SenderApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by: com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action. at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:55) ~[gax-1.60.1.jar!/:1.60.1] at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:72) ~[gax-grpc-1.60.1.jar!/:1.60.1] at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:60) ~[gax-grpc-1.60.1.jar!/:1.60.1] at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[gax-grpc-1.60.1.jar!/:1.60.1] at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:68) ~[api-common-1.10.1.jar!/:na] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1074) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar!/:na] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar!/:na] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar!/:na] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:983) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar!/:na] at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:771) ~[guava-30.0-jre.jar!/:na] at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:563) ~[grpc-stub-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533) ~[grpc-stub-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:464) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:428) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:461) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:617) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:803) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:782) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:123) ~[grpc-core-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_275] Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) ~[gax-1.60.1.jar!/:1.60.1] at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112) ~[gax-1.60.1.jar!/:1.60.1] at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.getTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:567) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.110.1.jar!/:1.110.1] at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.TopicAdminClient.getTopic(TopicAdminClient.java:498) ~[google-cloud-pubsub-1.110.1.jar!/:1.110.1] at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.PubSubAdmin.getTopic(PubSubAdmin.java:123) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.8.RELEASE] at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.ensureTopicExists(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.8.RELEASE] at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:65) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.8.RELEASE] at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.stream.binder.pubsub.provisioning.PubSubChannelProvisioner.provisionProducerDestination(PubSubChannelProvisioner.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder-1.2.8.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.8.RELEASE] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:223) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:91) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.doBindProducer(BindingService.java:320) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:285) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:294) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:298) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindableProxyFactory.createAndBindOutputs(AbstractBindableProxyFactory.java:142) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.doStartWithBindable(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:58) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedValues.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:608) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.AbstractBindingLifecycle.start(AbstractBindingLifecycle.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.OutputBindingLifecycle.start(OutputBindingLifecycle.java:34) [spring-cloud-stream-3.1.3.jar!/:3.1.3] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9] at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4] at com.pubsub.sender.SenderApplication.main(SenderApplication.java:12) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_275] at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action. at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:533) ~[grpc-api-1.34.1.jar!/:1.34.1] ... 17 common frames omitted`

`application.properties` file

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outgoing.destination=test
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.project-id=GCP_PROJECT_ID
```

SpringBoot Application uses workload identity and Service Account annotated with it has `Publisher` and `Subscriber` Roles applied.

Comment: Are both the GKE cluster and PubSub instance in the same GCP Project? 
Assuming they are, you might want to remove the `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.project-id` from your properties file

Comment: @GariSingh Yes both are in same project and removing project id also gives same error